# libuvc_camera - Camera Doesn't Respond To Parameter Changes

Tags: ros, logitech, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I have a Logitech C920 that I'm using with the libuvc_camera node. I've followed the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera. My goal is to disable auto focus and auto exposure and set them manually.

I can view the image stream (using the image_view node), so I know the camera works. I tried to disable auto focus/auto exposure via the libuvc_camera service, however the camera continued to to set the focus and exposure automatically. I tried to set other parameters such absolute exposure and focus, however the camera did not respond to these changes.

I confirmed that my desired parameter values were set by printing the current node configuration to console.

Does anyone have any idea why the camera isn't responding to these parameter changes? Do I need to run the libuvc_camera node as a super user or something?

Thank you for any insight.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99996/libuvc_camera---camera-doesn%27t-respond-to-parameter-changes/) by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-11-13**:
I had the same issue with the same camera. As far as I remember the problem was caused by not having write permissions to /dev/bus/usb. I don't think you need root permissions. Check the write permissions just like it's recommend here http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera

**Comment by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on 2013-11-13**:
I followed the instructions in that link, specifically I set " #UVC cameras
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", MODE="0666" " in my 99-uvc.rules file. I found that I was able to disable auto exposure, but I cannot manually set exposure time, the aperture, or disable auto focus. Could you?

**Comment by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on 2013-11-13**:
Were you able to control the iris or exposure manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible there's a permissions level issue. It's also possible that the camera simply does not support changing those modes.

There's a lot of the cheaper web cameras that simply don't implement the full specifications for the interface.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on 2013-11-12**:
Hi, thank you for your answer. We were actually able to control focus/exposure on this exact camera using libuvc in an OpenCV implementation. I don't see why ROS would be having this issue. I will try running libuvc_camera as a super user.